# AtomicReference vs AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater, what's a purpose of AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater?

Tags: java, multithreading, reflection, reference, atomic

I'd like to atomically upgrade my reference. For example to use `compareAndSet`, `getAndSet` and other atomic operations.

I came from C++, so in C++ I've got `volatile` keyword and different atomic intrinsics, or the `<atomic>` [API](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic). In java, there's also a `volatile` keyword and different [unsafe atomic operations](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Unsafe.java).

By the way, there's also a well-documented [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) (as well as `Long`, `Integer`, `Boolean`), so **JDK** creators provided us a way to safely execute atomic operations against references and primitives. There's nothing wrong about the API, it is rich and seems very familiar.

But, there's also an [AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.html) whick provides a kinda weird way to execute atomic operations: you have to "find" the field via reflection by name and then you can use exactly the same operations.

So my questions are:

1. What's the purpose of `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater` at all? In my
   opinion it is implicit and kinda weird: you need to declare a
   volatile variable filed **AND** and the field updater itself. So where
   should I use a `FieldUpdater`?
2. It provides an indirection: you're
   *manipulating* (not **changing**!) the `FieldUpdater`, not the variable, this confuses.
3. Performance: as far as I know, both `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater` and
   `AtomicReference` are delegating to the Unsafe, so their performance
   is similar, but anyway: are there any performance penalties of
   `FieldUpdater` agaist Reference?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's used to save memory.

[Example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.html) from the doc:

```
class Node {
   private volatile Node left, right;

   private static final AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater<Node, Node> leftUpdater =
     AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(Node.class, Node.class, "left");
   private static AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater<Node, Node> rightUpdater =
     AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(Node.class, Node.class, "right");

   Node getLeft() { return left; }
   boolean compareAndSetLeft(Node expect, Node update) {
     return leftUpdater.compareAndSet(this, expect, update);
   }
   // ... and so on
 }
```

it declares `left` and `right` as `Node` directly. And the `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater` is `static final`.

Without `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater`, you might need declare them as `AtomicReference<Node>`.

```
private  AtomicReference<Node> left, right;
```

**which consumes more memory than `Node`**. When there are many instances of `Node`, it consumes much more memory than first approach.